# Cant compare string with a excel cell data in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, string, excel-formula, openpyxl, string-comparison

I am trying to validate a string data with a list of excel data but it seems like "==" is not getting it. Can't figure out what is wrong here.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
import os.path
import os

text = "tag all door."

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\Document\\Schedulable Fields.xlsx', data_only=True)
def get_category(text):
    sh1 = wb['Categories']
    maxrow = sh1.max_row
    r = 1
    word = text.split()
    category = word[-1]
    if "s" not in category[-2:]:
        if category[-1] == ".":
            category = category.replace(".", "s")
        else:
            category = category + "s"
    elif "." == category[-1]:
        category = category.replace(".", "")
    else:
        pass
    for r in range(1, maxrow):
        item = sh1.cell(row=r, column=1).value
        print(item.casefold())
        print(category)
        if item.casefold() == category:
            break

        r += 1
    return item
```

This is the output that I got out of it as you can see the doors are a match but I am getting nothing....

```
doors 
doors
windows
doors
walls
doors
floors
doors
roofs
doors
Roofs
[Finished in 1.174s]
```

Comment: What do the `print` statements print? Are you sure that the characters are really the same (knowing that non-breakable spaces look just like normal spaces, for example)? Better compare the character codes of each character to be sure.

Comment: I have uploaded the output and I have also tried  .strip() for that still no luck.

Comment: add print(type(item.casefold()); print(category); and also change the output to print('>'+item.casefold()+'<'); print('>'+category+'<'); just to make sure that there are no other characters there. Is there any difference?

Comment: you are right there was a trailing space after door. I think I also had other issues that caused the failure when I first tried .strip() now as I have corrected them along the way they are working perfectly this time. Thanks to both of you.